# Handling base64String as response in Swift

Tags: ios, base64, alamofire, alamofireimage

- I am receiving a `base64String` for Image in response of an Api but
  unable to get the result through `Alamofire.request` method (tried
  with get as well as post).

  ```
   Alamofire.request(ApiUrl, method: .get, parameters: [:] , encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers:kAuthorizationHeader).responseString { (response) in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let responseString):
          if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: responseString),
              let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
              print("image")
          }
      case .failure(let error):
          print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }
  ```
- It always returns a failure with '*requestTimeOut*' in case of get
  method and '*Invalid value around character 0*' for post.

  Is there any way through which we can get the `base64String` so that I can convert the same to `UIImage`? Please advise.

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet?

Comment: Not a Good idea. You should discuss with your backend team to send the imageURL instead of base64String.

Comment: Due to security reasons/ permissions issue we cannot get url from backend. What can be other possible solution. Please share if any

Comment: For security purpose you should user access_token or signature like AWS does. base64String can be easily convert into readable form by using online tool.

Comment: bease64 is large data and should not be send or receive in API if this is heavy data like image.

Comment: I can tell you the solution but this is not recommended. Just extract the AlamoFire and check where the URLRequest object is being initialised and set the time out aprx 10*60 so that 10 minutes and it will work. But again it will not work if the data is larger than expected. So better to follow my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I went and created a view in my python project which responds a string in a url. So using alamofire.. you need to request string rather than responseJSON

```
Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:8000/stringResponse/", method: .get).responseString { (response) in
         switch response.result {
        case .success(let responseString):
            if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: responseString),
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                print("image")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working for me. Still getting "The request timed out." error

Comment: try it once with postman.. is it working with postman or any other api call tools?

Comment: are other apis working or is it all the api is giving timeout error?

Comment: Actually this does nothing with requestTimeOut error. It means the data is huge and the time out time set lesser than its needed.

Comment: if so, ask your backend developer to send the url for image source and use it with sdwebimage maybe